# Google Chrome отображает шрифты огромными пикселями

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, шрифты

На некоторых сайтах некоторые шрифты отображаются вот так:

[image: скриншот]

Пробовал удалять шрифты из системы - то же самое. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас какой-нибудь кривой шрифт PT Sans в винде не установлен?

Comment: >>Пробовал удалять шрифты из системы - то же самое